# How to make an Web Browser with Python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x

I trying to find out how to make an Web Browser using Python 3.8, but nothing works. Most of the tutorials or articles I find just opens links in Firefox (I use Firefox) using the webbrowser module. The rest of them use PyQt, which for some reason just doesn't work on my computer (I'm using Windows 10). When I import PyQt `from PyQt5.QtGui import QApplication` it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtGui'`. I'm trying to make it simple, just an search bar for getting the urls and a place to display the webpage. Maybe something like this:

[image]
**Mozarella Ashbadger browser made with PyQT**

Comment: Are you sure `PyQt` is installed? Your question is a mix of diffenrent question: (1) How to make a web browser with Python? (2) Why isn't `PyQt` not working? I think it would be better if you'd entangle them and then ask them in 2 separate questions.

Comment: I installed PyQt by running `pip install pyqt5` in the terminal. I also tried `pip install python-qt5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyQt5 went through some changes in the last few years which might be causing your issues.

I have tested the following method recently as part of a package I recently made with a integrated webbrowser, so as of writing (October 2020) it will work.

First you need to also install an additional module `PyQtWebEngine`. then the following code should open a single page.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
 
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
 
web = QWebEngineView()
web.load(QUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/"))
web.show()
 
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Anything more than that will require some UI work, but it should be easier now that you have the web part of it handled.

Comment: I tried your code, but Python 3.8.5 displayed this message: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Browser.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore: The specified module could not be found.`. Also,  I replaced my name with USER.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer worked! I just had to do it in a virtual environment.

Comment: Just one question though: How can I make the HTML bigger?

Comment: What do you mean by that? You mean the window size bigger or the text in the window bigger?

Comment: The text and components in the window. Everything inside is smaller than what is displayed in Firefox. I tried going full screen, but it is still is too small. Here is a comparison: **Firefox:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dCo3lYo8d9PnbLhLB3sFL4cEGzRaJfN6/view?usp=sharing | **PyQt5 WebBrowser:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/13ul7iwAKdK5MgFXI7dugQDq8k5MlBwyt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Never Mind, I just found out how make it bigger. I used [this documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#zoomFactor-prop)

Comment: My new code is:`import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
 
web = QWebEngineView()
web.load(QUrl(url))
web.setZoomFactor(2)
web.zoomFactor()
web.show()
 
sys.exit(app.exec_())`

Comment: Sorry for the messed up code. I can't press enter, or else StackOverflow will just send my comment.